# ASP.NET Identity password requirements overriding my own

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

So I need to import a bunch of users into my ASP.NET Identity based system and some of he passwords are very short (as little as three characters) and beyond my control. I need to import these passwords so existing users can login and change their passwords to meet a more stringent requirement.

I thought that by configuring the `PasswordValidator` property in my `ApplicationUserManager` class I could set the requirements for the imported password to a low number allowing me to import the existing user.

```
// Configure validation logic for passwords
appUserManager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
{
    RequiredLength = 3,
    RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
    RequireDigit = false,
    RequireLowercase = false,
    RequireUppercase = false,
};
```

However when I import users and try and create a new record I get a validation error in the `IdentityResult`.

```
IdentityResult result = manager.Create(newUser, importedUser.Password);
```

`result.Errors = "Passwords must be at least 6 characters."`

Is it not possible to override the Identity default requirements?

Here is the entire ApplicationUserManager class for reference:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
        PasswordValidator = new MinimumLengthValidator(3);
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var appDbContext = context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var appUserManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(appDbContext));

        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        appUserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(appUserManager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = true,
            RequireUniqueEmail = false
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        appUserManager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 3,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = false,
            RequireLowercase = false,
            RequireUppercase = false,
        };

        appUserManager.EmailService = new Services.EmailService();

        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            appUserManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"))
            {
                //Code for email confirmation and reset password life time
                TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(6)
            };
        }

        return appUserManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: I searched my project for the error text `Passwords must be at least X characters` and could not find it at all. This leads me to believe it is a built in requirement of the Identity framework.

Comment: Can you show the code before `IdentityResult result = manager.Create(newUser, importedUser.Password);`? How did you get the `manager` object?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The `ApplicationUserManager` class I listed above is called from the API controllers. However, I was trying to import users into the database outside of the API. So what I needed to do was place the password validation override inside the method where I was importing users. Specifically where I instantiated the `manager`. Here is an example:

```
foreach (var user in UserList)
{
    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
    manager.PasswordValidator = new MinimumLengthValidator(3);

    var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

    var newUser = new ApplicationUser()
    {
        UserName = user.UserName,
        UserId = user.UserId,
        Email = user.Email,
        FirstName = user.FirstName,
        LastName = user.LastName,
    };


    // Assign the password
    IdentityResult result = manager.Create(newUser, user.Password);

    // Assign the role
    var addedUser = manager.FindByName(user.UserName);
    manager.AddToRoles(addedUser.Id, new string[] { "User" });

}
```

Notice the line `manager.PasswordValidator = new MinimumLengthValidator(3);`. Here is where I define the password override. Previously I was placing the password override in the `ApplicationUserManager` class thinking it would cover all instances of the `manager` creation. The solution was to define the password override where the `ApplicationUserManager` class was used. Sorry for the self answer but I wanted to write up the solution in case others ran into the same problem.

Comment: Hello, as I was maintaining an existing web form project and updating it to asp.net identity, I faced the same difficulty and saw your solution. My gratitude is in order. One question, though. why does the password validator doesn't apply?

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.config file to make sure it doesn't have a minimum password length requirement in it that is overriding everything else.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but nothing in the web.config relating to password.